# Dynamically load tokens with react AcceptJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authorize.net

I am trying to use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-acceptjs/v/0.3.0

The problem I am having is I am using multiple Autnorize.net keys.  I need to make an API request to get the key and then load if but hooks cant be loaded conditionally so how do I make the api request before I pass the value to `useAcceptJs()`?

This is demo

```
import { useAcceptJs } from 'react-acceptjs';

const authData = {
  apiLoginID: 'YOUR AUTHORIZE.NET API LOGIN ID',
  clientKey: 'YOUR AUTHORIZE.NET PUBLIC CLIENT KEY',
};

type BasicCardInfo = {
  cardNumber: string;
  cardCode: string;
  month: string;
  year: string;
};

const App = () => {
  const { dispatchData, loading, error } = useAcceptJs({ authData });
  const [cardData, setCardData] = React.useState<BasicCardInfo>({
    cardNumber: '',
    month: '',
    year: '',
    cardCode: '',
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Dispatch CC data to Authorize.net and receive payment nonce for use on your server
    const response = await dispatchData({ cardData });
    console.log('Received response:', response);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="cardNumber"
        value={cardData.cardNumber}
        onChange={(event) =>
          setCardData({ ...cardData, cardNumber: event.target.value })
        }
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="month"
        value={cardData.month}
        onChange={(event) =>
          setCardData({ ...cardData, month: event.target.value })
        }
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="year"
        value={cardData.year}
        onChange={(event) =>
          setCardData({ ...cardData, year: event.target.value })
        }
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="cardCode"
        value={cardData.cardCode}
        onChange={(event) =>
          setCardData({ ...cardData, cardCode: event.target.value })
        }
      />
      <button type="submit" disabled={loading || error}>
        Pay
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I cannot figure out how I can dynamically add in the authData and update it when needed.

Anyone have any ideas?